# "Login failed for user" issue for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to SQL azure database from C# code using Visual studio 2012. I have already done client IP setup and I can able to connect database through management studio. Also, **connection.open** method is working fine but When I run SQLdataAdapter **Fill** Method its throwing exception as "Login failed for user" with some GUID number.

Could you please assist me on this?

Comment: please paste the entire exception as text

Comment: Are both connection strings using the Default Catalog setting to log straight into the user database, and not log in to the master database?

Comment: Can you perform the same select in SSMS with the same credentials the application is using?

Comment: Its working now. Actually I was opening a connection for disconnected scenarios. that's why it was throwing that exception.